# Matlab. Extract specific data from struct field

Tags: matlab, struct, finance

I have 66 csv files containing historical data from stocks.
At first i used this in order to import the data for my analysis but it is very time consuming for 66 csv files.

```
ADBE1=readtable('ADBE.csv');
Close=ADBE1(:,5);
ADBE=table2array(Close);
```

So later on i tried to make a struck from the directory , containing all the csv files, so that i could extract from each file the fifth column into a new matrix Y that will contain the closing prices from all stocks.

''' files = dir('*.csv'); '''
Now that my struct is created, i must reach each ''' files.name ''' with a loop and take the data. But how do i take the first file of files.name? ( something like files.name(i) ).
Thanks in advance

Comment: `files(i).name` ?

Comment: There are many questions on here about “how to read all xxx-type files in a directory”. I suggest you look at some of those to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

You get create a cell array of all the file name by doing

```matlab
filenames = {files(:).name}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now i can loop for all files and extract the data i want.